# SharePoint online "Site Closure and Deletion" setting not available

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am working on SharePoint online sites, where I need to activate policy to lock the site from modification. I wants to achieve the same using "Policies" and "Site Closure and Deletion". But I can not see it in site settings.[image: image attached where these settings are missing]

Someone have sent me this snap and it is quite visible there like this
[image: this should be visible to my site collection settings]

Please guide if I need to activate any feature or some other settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer, In order to get this settings and policy visible we need to activate the feature "Site Policy".

[image]